# Decommission Publication Target method is not working in Tridion 2013 SP1 in our environment

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

We have unused Publication targets which needs to be deleted and we thought of using the new 2013 Sp1 feature of decommission the targets.
We used the below method

```
 client.DecommissionPublicationTarget("tcm:0-14-65537");
```

This line executes successfully without any error but the publication target doesn't get deleted.
Do we need to perform any other extra steps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation states:

> Decommissions (takes out of service) a Publication Target, **so it can be deleted afterwards**.

I would therefore assume that, yes, you need to delete it afterwards yourself.

Something like:

```
client.Delete("tcm:0-14-65537");
```

after calling `DecommissionPublicationTarget()` should be sufficient.

Comment: That's indeed how it was designed to work, we thought that the actual delete decision should come from the "owner" rather than the API, in case you were just trying to clean up

Comment: As @Nuno mentioned, by design, but that also makes it useful and a lot more safe. See also my blog post on this http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/decommission-a-publication-target and the sample code of how it could be used in a UI extension https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/Decommission+Publication+Target/trunk/ (note I'm also not deleting the target in my extension, but that could be added by changing a single line of code as David explains).

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to use PowerShell and run:

Clear-TcmPublicationTarget tcm:x-x-x